# How to add a csrf_token to a dynamically generated form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have a dynamically generated form but I can't do anything with it since Django required a `csrf_token` in every POST form.

My form is generated via:

```
$("#results").append(
  '<form class="form-book-add" id="{0}" method="post" action="/books/add/">'
  // Django requires a CSRF token here. How do I add it via Javascript?
  + '<input type="hidden" id="book-asin" value="'+asin+'"/>'
  + '<input type="hidden" id="book-title" value="'+details['title']+'"/>'
  + '<input type="hidden" id="book-author" value="'+details['author']+'"/>'
  + '<input type="hidden" id="book-cover" value="'+details['cover']+'"/>'
  + '<input type="hidden" id="book-url" value="'+details['url']+'"/>'
  + '<input type="hidden" id="book-isbn" value="'+details['isbn']+'"/>'
  + '<input type="submit" id="btn-book-add" value="Add"/>'
  + '</form></div>'.format(i)
);
```

Comment: If your form is generated dynamically django template engine will not parse it thus you do not need CSRF token. Or i have missed something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have 2 options, first exclude csrf verification for the view - easiest, unsecure.

second, set `input` of `csrfmiddlewaretoken` to the value from the cookie `csrftoken`.

[django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax) has a nice example of something similar (from that example you will need just the part which extracts cookie value).